# Wordpress: Left join php mysql very slow

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I use this code for select count of posts

```
$select = SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT wpPost.ID )
          FROM `wp_posts` wpPost
          RIGHT JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` wpOrderItem
          ON wpOrderItem.`meta_value`='6246'
          WHERE wpPost.`post_status`='wc-completed'
          GROUP BY wpPost.`ID`
          ORDER BY wpPost.`post_date` DESC
$wpdb->get_results("$select");
echo $wpdb->num_rows;
```

But this code is very slow and long time about 40 sec!

`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` have 388116 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One reason DISTINCT should be used only when absolutely necessary is
>   that the result set must be sorted in order to find and remove
>   duplicates

I am not sure why your query is taking a long time, but I have one workaround, sum count by removing distinct from query.

Arbitrarily choosing to keep the minimum ID. Also, avoid using the implicit join syntax.

Your Query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT( wpPost.ID ), MIN( wpPost.ID)
FROM `wp_posts` wpPost
RIGHT JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` wpOrderItem
ON wpOrderItem.`meta_value`='6246'
WHERE wpPost.`post_status`='wc-completed'
GROUP BY wpPost.`ID`
ORDER BY wpPost.`post_date` DESC
```

Comment: I remove DISTINCT but not affect

Comment: check indexing, apply indexing as per condition, it will help

Comment: apply composite index on id, post_status and post_date

Answer (score 0):

I would start with adding the following indexes to optimize this query:

```
ALTER TABLE
  `wp_posts`
ADD
  INDEX `wp_posts_index_1` (`post_status`, `ID`);

ALTER TABLE
  `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`
ADD
  INDEX `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_index_1` (`meta_value`);
```